# Converting Recursive Query from Week over Week to Month over Month

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have a recursive query that provides the number of orders placed week over week (week_no, week_start, and week_end). I'd like to create a similar breakdown for a month over month analysis.

```
WITH recursive weeks (week_start, week_end, time_end, weekno) AS (
VALUES ('2015-12-27'::date, '2016-01-02'::date, '2016-04-02'::date, 1) 
UNION ALL 
SELECT (week_end + interval '1 day')::date, 
       (CASE 
              WHEN (week_end + interval '7 days')::date > time_end THEN time_end 
              ELSE (week_end + interval '7 days')::date 
       END)::date, 
       time_end, 
       weekno+1 
FROM   weeks 
WHERE  time_end > week_end)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you use a recursive query for this?  Use `generate_series()`:

```
select g.week_start, g.week_start + interval '6 day' as week_end,
       row_number() over (order by g.week_start) as weeknum
from generate_series('2015-12-27'::timestamp,
                     '2016-01-02'::timestamp,
                     interval '1 week'
                    ) g(week_start);
```

The equivalent for months would be like:

```
select g.month_start, g.month_start + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day' as month_end,
       row_number() over (order by g.month_start) as monthnum
from generate_series('2015-12-01'::timestamp,
                     '2016-01-01'::timestamp,
                     interval '1 month'
                    ) g(month_start);
```